# UITableView Current section floating not where it should

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

An image is worth a 1000 words, so here is a screen :

[image]

As you can see, the "A" section is the current section and there is space above it and I can't understand why.

FWIW : It's a `UISearchResultsTableView` (`UITableView` subclass) create by a `UISearchDisplayController`.

This problem appear I think after some changed in the interface builder but I can't find what exactly.

It look likes it the space is the same height as the navigationbar.

Answer (score 0):

By default, `UITableViewController`'s views are automatically inset in iOS 7 so that they don't start below the navigation bar/status bar.

This is controller by the **Adjust scroll view insets** setting on the Attributes Inspector tab of the `UITableViewController` in Interface Builder, or by the `setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:` method of `UIViewController`.

For a `UIViewController`'s contents, if you don't want its view's contents to extend under the top/bottom bars, you can use the *Extend Edges Under Top Bars/Under Bottom Bars* settings in Interface Builder. This is accessible via the `edgesForExtendedLayout` property.

Try:

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;        
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

Comment: Yeah I thought of that but    `_searchController.searchContentsController.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`
    `_searchController.searchContentsController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;` did nothing.

Comment: Any solution found yet? I'm having the same problem.